# Python type of `def`

Tags: python

Python 3.6

Can someone explain this console output?

Just started looking at the asyncio stuff and though I'd confirm how to create coroutines and the like. It seems like using `def` always gives you a class `function`

```
>>> async def test():
...     pass
... 
>>> type(test)
<class 'function'> # Why not 'coroutine'?

>>> def test():
...     yield
...     
>>> type(test)
<class 'function'>

>>> test = (i for i in range(0))
>>> type(test)
<class 'generator'> # Expected

>>> def test():
...     for i in range(0):
...         yield i
...         
>>> type(test)
<class 'function'> # Why not 'generator'?
```

Comment: try `x=test()` then `type(x)`.

Comment: Ok, but when I call it. You get what is on the return or yield... not a `X` - Posted before i saw ^

Comment: @JamesSchinner: no you don't.

Comment: @JamesSchinner: you get a generator or coroutine. You then can *iterate over the generator* to get the yielded values, or *await on the coroutine*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still have regular functions. These functions **produce** a generator or coroutine, they are not the generator or coroutine themselves.

Compare the generator function with one that returns a generator expression:

```
def test():
    return (i for i in range(0))
```

Like a function using `yield`, the above function only produces the generator when you call it; this lets you produce *multiple, independent generators*; the generator expression on the other hand can only be iterated over once.

The same applies to coroutines. You can produce a function that returns a coroutine without using `async`:

```
def test():
    return asyncio.sleep(0)
```

The point of an async function or a generator function is to act as a factory; you can *repeatedly* call them to produce a new coroutine or generator.

Comment: Wow... That moment when your mental model of python that worked perfectly fine up. Just explodes... Thanks for the explanation